# I have an answer for my "too broad" keyboard question that was closed yesterday - shall we re-open it, or forget it?

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question

So my question [What could have caused the * key on my numeric keypad to stop working in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/1014996/what-could-have-caused-the-key-on-my-numeric-keypad-to-stop-working-in-windows) got deleted yesterday as too broad. I just voted to undelete it today, because I figured out the problem.

However if this seems like not a good question for the site, never mind. My answer is kind of like the related question where the person found that Texter software was intercepting some keys.

I followed the comment's suggestion to re-seat the key, but waited for the problem to happen again. That wasn't it.

In my case, it was another particular piece of software I'd not have suspected to intercept keystrokes, but it was. Going into options, I was able to un-map those keys.

Comment: You should edit the question to include the things you tried from your comments. Like cleaning under the key. I've voted to reopen as you have a solution to post but others may feel it is still too broad.

Comment: Currently it need one more undelete vote.

Comment: If you politely ask on http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access (with a link to this question) you _may_ get another vote ;)

Answer (score 1):

Undeleted and reopened.

This is the right site for these questions, but it is difficult to diagnose intermittent faults and your question doesn't give any hints as to how to replicate the problem.

If you have found what was intercepting the keys then feel free to give more info on how to replicate the problem in your question (if relevant) and post what you did to stop it in an answer.

As you are self posting an answer you may need to wait a day before you can accept it though.

Comment: Thanks. I edited and answered. It is similar to another question and answer, which I mentioned - the difference is just the particular software intercepting the keystrokes.